Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed, but "connection.getLatestBlockhash()" works
My script breaks at a contract function call on line number 250 with an error
:

but the connection.getLatestBlockhash works on line number 241:

with this on the console
:


does this work calling it subsequently one after another?

Now it works, i missed declaring the provider.

I did not declare provider at the start, you can do this by
 anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());


Try using a new RPC provider like Helius for your connection string.

Thankyou for your recommendation, but the RPC service provider was not the issue, I didn't declare the provider only in my setup.
